# Show that $A+H$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $|Ax|\geq\alpha |x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and some $\alpha>0$. The first part of the question is show that $A$ is invertible and that $||A^{-1}||\leq\alpha^{-1}$, where $||\cdot||$ represent the operator norm.

$Ax=0\iff |Ax|=0\iff x=0$ since $\alpha>0$, which means $\ker(A)=\{0\}$ and hence $A$ is injective and therefore invertible.

$||A||=\sup_{x}\frac{|Ax|}{|x|}\geq\alpha$ and so $||A^{-1}||\leq||A||^{-1}\leq\alpha$. Is this first part correct?

I'm not sure whether my solution to second part is correct.

Now suppose $H$ is also an $n\times n$ matrix such that $||H||\leq\alpha-\delta$ for some $\delta\in[0,\alpha)$. I'm asked to show that $A+H$ is invertible.

Consider

$|(A+H)x|=|Ax+Hx|\geq|Ax|-|Hx|\geq\alpha|x|-||H|||x|\geq\alpha|x|-(\alpha-\delta)|x|=\delta|x|$

I'm trying to use the same argument as before that $A+H$ must be injective, but wouldn't I need $\delta\in(0,\alpha)$?

Comment: I think what you have is right... and yes delta should be in some open interval... otherwise consider A being the identity matrix and H being the negative of A

Comment: No, the first part is not correct. First, you're missing a reciprocal. More important, where did you get $\|A^{-1}\\le \|A\|^{-1}$?